# Qemu does not shutdown with vnc enabled on OS X

Tags: java, macos, vnc, qemu

I am trying to run Qemu on my Mac and I have some difficulties. 
I am using OS X 10.8.2 and installed Qemu 1.2.50 via their repository.

**Update**:
Just upgraded to Qemu 1.3.50 and the problem is still the same.

When I run

```
qemu-system-i386
```

from the command line everything works well and I can terminate execution using Ctrl-C.
As soon as I add -vnc :0 however I am no longer able to terminate without killing the process from the Activity Monitor.

My problem is, that I am not just starting Qemu manually from time to time but that I have a Java program that requieres Qemu to perform some task via the vnc protocol, so manual shutdown is not an option.

So basically at some point in my program I start a thread that does:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
process = rt.exec("/usr/local/bin/qemu-system-i386 -vnc :0");
// Some stuff via vnc protocol
```

At some later point from my main thread I call:

```
process.destroy();
```

This does not terminate Qemu on OS X. The same code works with Qemu 1.2.0 on Ubuntu 12.10

So I guess my question is **how to properly shutdown Qemu with vnc enabled on OS X**.

Or maybe I could just try to force-quit the Qemu process like the Activity Manager does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update on August 18th, 2017**: The issue appears to be resolved with QEMU version 2.9.0

---

I filed a bug report at Qemu and got a response:

> Interesting -- my experience is that control-C doesn't work at all, even if using the cocoa UI frontend. It's a bug of some kind related to signal handling but I haven't been able to track it down. As far as I could tell with a debugger QEMU never received the SIGTERM at all, which makes no sense to me.
>
> As a workaround you can send QEMU a SIGKILL, which will abruptly terminate QEMU (NB that if you have a writable disk image you may find it is corrupt since this is a long way from a clean shutdown). The best approach would be to make the guest cleanly power down the VM, which should cause QEMU to exit automatically.

From: [Qemu Bug tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu/+bug/1089005)

Comment: on 2017-04-07: He asked you if the issue is still reproducible  with the
latest version of QEMU (version 2.9)?

on 2017-06-07 [Expired for QEMU because there has been no activity for 60 days.]